# E4X in Actionscript 3 throwing variable not defined error

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, e4x

I've been using E4X expressions and it has never caused a problem. Today I got this error which is driving me crazy. Checked everything thousand times, searched web, but nothing.

So this is my query for the value:

```
var objectName:String = myXML.objects.object.(@id==objectId);
```

where objectId is an **int**.

This is the part of my XML:

```
<objects>

    <object id="0">value 1</object>
    <object id="1">value 2</object>
    <object id="2">value 3</object>

</objects>
```

When the above line is run I get an error which seems like a total nonsense to me:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable id is not defined.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because not all of your `object` nodes has the `id` attribute, try more safety way to search through the attributes with `hasOwnProperty("@id")` checks:

```
    var objectName:String = 
        xml.objects.object.(hasOwnProperty("@id") && @id=="2");
```

Comment: Actually all of my "object" nodes have an attribute `id`, but thanks for your approach.

Comment: Now I'm getting a "Value is not a function" error message, as I also manipulate the string I get from XML. I think something's wrong with either my XML or my code. Going to debug further. Thanks

Comment: After debugging my XML I found out that somehow `xml.objects` only contains first `object` node, which doesn't have an `id` listed when traced. Any opinions?

Comment: After further debugging I found out my code was messing things up, when I tried to replace all the `\\n` characters with `\n`s. Strange..